# Nexus Sonatype Logging issue after Initial Setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, repository, nexus, sonatype

Just installed Sonatype Nexus on an ec2 server(centos 7). It lets me log in with username and  password from the opt path but no setup wizard pops up. I can't change the password to one of my choice. I can't enable or disable anonymous user. In addition to that, the administration menu with the 'settings' icon that's usually to the left of the search bar isn't there. Is there something  I may have missed? I can`t make any changes nor create new users and when I refresh the page it logs out automatically. I have tried different web browsers but no luck. Please see attachments. It seems to me that for whatever reason, changes are not saved.

PS: Please ignore the version as i am trying different versions to see if it fixes the issue. I tried the latest version as well but that also did not help.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]